# How to Verify I/O on MyPi

Tags: gpio

I need to figure out how to force the relay outputs on/off manually using Pi command prompts. How can i check for a high/low output on each GPIO pin?

Comment: Ah, multi-meter is my friend.

Comment: need to use command prompts :/

Comment: And I often use a always connected red status LED with a 1k series resister at the GPIO pin, as an alarm signal that the relay has switched on the nuclear reactor or coffee pot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any GPIO library will let you test the levels of the GPIO.

One method using my pigpio library and the pigs utility.

```
# start the pigpio daemon

sudo pigpiod

# read GPIO 2 to 27

for ((i=2; i<28; i++)); do echo "GPIO $i is"; pigs r $i; done
```